# Android bottom navigation bar item background color change when fragment selected

Tags: android, android-support-design

I want my bottom nav bar change background color when pressed ( only the selected area ) , 
Like the link bellow :

http://uupload.ir/files/nq3k_tab_bar.jpg

Here`s my xml for the selector :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/beyez" />
    <item android:state_active="true" app:itemBackground="@color/backbeyez"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"  />
</selector>
```

Here`s the xml for the activity :

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_items_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_items_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="515dp">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Here`s the code for my Java Class :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    switchorders();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottomnav);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);


    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.navigation_orders:
                    switchorders();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_credit:
                    switchcredits();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_works:
                    switchworks();
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    switchprofile();
                    break;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Thank you all for helping out !

Comment: Please edit the question to specify your exact problem in implementing this. Also edit the question to add your code in code blocks. You can keep the link if you want, but we prefer code blocks here as links can break in the future. This puts future people coming here with the same problem at a disadvantage since they can't see the code.

Comment: url is just taking to website. Not showing any image.

Comment: @SripadRaj url edited, tnx for the notice

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just change the line `app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"` in the xml for the `BottomNavigationView` to be a drawable object like you did for the other parameters (like `app:itemTextColor`).

**Edit**

This should work, I tried it with SDK > 19

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_orange_light"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: The parameter for app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary" can not be set a drawable, The app crashes

Comment: I updated the answer, the one I provided should work!