# How to change color of navigation bar elements when they are selected ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android, android-xml

I want to change the color of the navigation element when its selected

[menu i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RMYn.png)

for example when clicking on the Calculations element I want the background to be a light color

[menu i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksZDe.png)

Also i want to change font of the text in menu bar, but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

You can do by changing background colour of layout on setOnClickListener event of that button like below.

**xml File of navigation menu**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/nonitemclicked"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_calculator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_calculator"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_calculator"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_calculator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotoslabregular"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Calculation"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_list"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotoslabregular"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Calculation list"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ly_setting"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_setting"
                android:layout_width="28dp"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_setting"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_setting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotoslabregular"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="Setting"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Code**

setOnClickListner of buttons

```
        ly_calculator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setcolorOnItemClick(ly_calculator, ly_list, ly_setting);
            }
        });
        ly_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setcolorOnItemClick(ly_list, ly_calculator, ly_setting);
            }
        });
        ly_setting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setcolorOnItemClick(ly_setting, ly_calculator, ly_list);
            }
        });
```

Method for changing background colour

```
public void setcolorOnItemClick(LinearLayout ly1, LinearLayout ly2, LinearLayout ly3) {
        ly1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.itemclicked));
        ly2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nonitemclicked));
        ly3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.nonitemclicked));
    }
```

**And for change font of the text**

You can do using fontFamily in xml side and i have some font in font folder

```
android:fontFamily="@font/robotoslabregular"
```

You can also do by programmatically using typeface:

```
txt_calculator.setTypeface(getResources().getFont(R.font.robotoslabmedium));
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for this detailed response, but can i customize the bar menu that comes from the android studio box without creating special xml files that describe the logic of my menu ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable file of this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="your_active_color" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="your_inactive_color"/>
</selector>
```

Then put it in this attribute of bottom nav bar `app:itemBackground="@color/your_file"`

The full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45547368/12697321). May it help you